# Should I nest static or not static interfaces within a parent interface

Tags: java, bean-validation

To create conditionally validated groups with jsr 303 validation, an interface class is passed to the annotation like this:

```
@NotEmpty (groups={UpdateValue.class})
```

I have quite a few different interface types that I want to group in a parent interface in order to organize my code.  Is this pattern ok?  Should the child interfaces be static or non-static?  Should the parent interface be static or non-static?

Here's an example of the interface I want to create:

```
package com.value.validationTypes;
public interface IValidation {
    public interface NewValue {
    }
    public interface UpdateValue {
    }
}
```

and the way I would use it in my form bean:

```
@NotEmpty (groups={IValidation.UpdateValue.class})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner interfaces are implicitly `public static`, they cannot be anything else.

Whether you make them explicitly `public` or `static` is a matter of taste IMHO.